# Replacing elements of a list with those from another list based on name

Tags: r, list, dataframe, lapply

I'm trying to use the named index to replace some elements of a list.

I have three lists:

- Superset
- Subset
- SubsetNames

My objective is to replace the old elements in Superset with the corresponding ones from Subset where Name(Subset) == Name(Superset).

Example Code (Edited for correctness):

```
# Setting things up
Superset <- list(1, 2, 3, 4)
names(Superset) <- c("a", "b", "c", "d")

Subset <- list(5, 6)
names(Subset) <- c("b", "c") # or any names from Superset

SubsetNames <- as.list(names(Subset))
```

I have tried things like this:

```
lapply(SubsetNames, FUN=function(x) Superset[[x]] <- Subset[[x]])
```

And:

```
Superset[SubsetNames] <- Subset
```

I even tried to construct a for-loop with a counter however this is not a working solution in my scenario.

In reality, Superset is a list of dataframes, each of which has almost 90k datapoints in 117 columns.
Some of those dataframes need some tweaking.  I have code which successfully extracts a list of the ones needing tweaking and tweaks them... now I just need to put them back.

Your help much appreciated!  Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use the `names` of the 'Subset' to subset the 'Superset' and assign it to values of 'Subset'

```
Superset[names(Subset)] <- Subset
Superset
#$a
#[1] 1

#$b
#[1] 5

#$c
#[1] 6

#$d
#[1] 4
```

---

The `list` creation seems to be faulty.  It would be `as.list`

```
Superset <- as.list(1:4)
```

It will return a `list` of `length` 4 as opposed to `length` 1 with `list(1:4)`

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the fault.  I re-ran the code in RStudio and updated the question with what was running.

Comment: Also thanks for the answer!!!   ```Superset[names(Subset)] <- Subset``` works with my example code!

Comment: @SwiftArrow  Now you  are unnecessarily converting to `list` `SubsetNames <- as.list(names(Subset))`

Comment: for some reason I had an error without that, putting it in made it work.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change for every value in Subset, you could just do

```
modifyList(Superset, Subset)
```

or if you are just updating a smaller set of values from subset

```
modifyList(Superset, Subset[SubsetNames])
```